# How to display parameter from URL to template in class based views in Django

Tags: django

View below prints list of all posts done by certain user. User was a parameter taken from the URL and is working fine.

How do I extract **kwarg -> 'username' and display it on the template as a variable?

Things commented out in the code have been tried.

views.py

```py
class AuthorPostIndexView(ListView):
    model = Person
    template_name ='authorpostindex.html'
    context_object_name = 'author_post'

    #1)
    #date=request.GET.get('username','') -> wrong as varibales in classes
    #is not possible?

    #-> this works fine:

    def get_queryset(self):
        username = self.kwargs['username']
        queryset = Person.objects.get(username=username).post.all()
        return queryset, (username,'')



    #-> attempts to extract username kwarg:
    
    #2)
    # def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    #     context = super(AuthorPostIndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    #     context['username'] = self.username
    #     return context

    #3)
    # @property
    # def username(self):
    #    return self.kwargs['username']
```

expected result

template.html

```
<h1>{{username}}</h1> -> username from the URL should be displayed
```

Error messages:

## 1)'request' is not defined (shell)

## 2) 'AuthorPostIndexView' object has no attribute 'username' (template)

## 3) Reverse for 'post_detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post\/(?P[0-9]+)$'] (template)

ps. Still not working after advices:

Solutions looks similar however I think I have problem with getting the kwarg argument out of the method. In addition I lost confidence on what to put in the template.

Can I return two arguments in the function like that?

```
class AuthorPostIndexView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name ='authorpostindex.html'
    context_object_name = 'author_post'

    def get_queryset(self):
       queryset = super().get_queryset()
       username = self.kwargs['username']

       return (queryset.filter(authors__username=username),username)
```

Or in one of the suggested solution I have added method to the view

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AuthorPostIndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['username'] = self.kwargs['username']
        
        return context
```

...and then what about template

authorpostindex.html

```
{{context}}
or
{{username}}
or
{{context.username}}
```

That is not working

Comment: 2) should work if you either uncomment 3) at the same time, or change the line to `context['username'] = self.kwargs['username']`

Comment: 1) doesn't work because you should use `self.kwargs` instead of `request`, and in any case you can't access `self.kwargs` or `request` at the class level.

Comment: How is this different from the question I answered for you yesterday? I showed you exactly what to do there.

Comment: For some reason I can get queryset from the method but not the kwarg. I have added 'ps.' section as the end of question to clarify.

Comment: Don't change your `get_queryset` method like in your update. The original version was fine. If you set `context['username']` in the `get_context_data` method, then use `{{ username }}` in the template.

Comment: Crucial advice for my newbie skills. Thanks Alasdair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(AuthorPostIndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    context['username'] = self.kwargs['username']
    # or
    context['username'] = self.request.GET.get('username', None)

    return context
```

hope it helps